# Can't npm install googleapis

Tags: node.js, npm-install, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer

> node version: 8.9.3
>
> npm version: 5.5.1

When I try to execute `npm install googleapis` I'm getting this result:

> npm WARN eslint-config-standard@6.2.1 requires a peer of
> eslint@>=3.8.1 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself. npm WARN eslint-config-standard@6.2.1 requires
> a peer of eslint-plugin-promise@>=3.3.0 but none is installed. You
> must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
> eslint-config-standard@6.2.1 requires a peer of
> eslint-plugin-standard@>=2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install
> peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! Cannot read property '0' of undefined

What can I do? google apis package is not adding to the node_modules folder

I'm on windows 10